# RS232 transmitter module in vhdl latches?

Tags: serial-port, vhdl

I'm trying to write RS232 transmitter module in vhdl for Spartan. According to simulation in Xilinx, it seems to be working fine, but when i try to deploy it on device, it simply doesn't work. I have found out that it might be problem with latches, but somehow I'm not able to pinpoint them. I'm using 50 Mhz clock and the bit rate of transmission is 115200 bs.

This is my vhdl code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all; -- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity nadajnikRS is
    Port ( start : in  STD_LOGIC;
           reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
              DI : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           RS_TX : out  STD_LOGIC;
           busy : out  STD_LOGIC);
end nadajnikRS;

architecture Behavioral of transRS is
signal register : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0) := (others => '1' );
signal counter : INTEGER  range 0 to 9 := 0;
signal baud_clk : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal ready : STD_LOGIC := '0';
type states is (working, free);
signal state: states := free;
signal baud_counter : INTEGER range 0 to 220 := 215;
begin

baud_clock: process (clk)
begin

if rising_edge(clk) then
    if (ready = '1') then
        if (baud_counter < 218) then
            if (baud_counter = 217) then
                baud_clk <= '1';
            end if;
            baud_counter <= baud_counter+1;
        else
            baud_counter <= 0;
            baud_clk <= '0';
        end if;
    else
        baud_counter <= 0;
    end if; 

end if;

end process baud_clock;

shiftregister : process (baud_clk)
begin

    if rising_edge(baud_clk) then
        if (state = free) then
            RS_TX <= '0';
            register (7 downto 0) <= DI;

        else  
            RS_TX <= register(0);
            register <= '1' & register(8 downto 1);
        end if;


    end if;
end process shiftregister;

bitcounter : process (baud_clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(baud_clk) then
        counter <= counter + 1;
            if (counter = 10) then
                counter <= 1;
            end if;
    end if;
end process bitcounter;

shiftstate: process (reset, counter, start)
begin
    if (reset = '1') then
        ready <= '0';
    end if;
    if (start = '1') then
        ready <= '1';
        state <= free;
    end if;
    if (counter = 1 ) then
        state <= working;
    elsif (counter = 10) then
        state <= free;
    end if;
end process;

statemachine : process (state)
begin
    case state is 
    when working => busy <= '1';
    when free => busy <= '0' ;
    end case;

end process statemachine; 

end Behavioral;
```

During synthesis I get two latch warnings:

```
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <ready>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
Xst:737 - Found 1-bit latch for signal <state_0>. Latches may be generated from incomplete case or if statements. We do not recommend the use of latches in FPGA/CPLD designs, as they may lead to timing problems.
```

I tried to eliminate them by adding additional if statements, but nothing seems to work.
I will be grateful for any help,
Ghaad

Answer (score 1):

A process describing a register should have exactly one signal in the sensitivity list, clk (possibly a reset signal as well if you use asynchronous resets), since a register is only sensitive to a single event, namely a clock edge.

Thus your process sensitivity list `baud_clock: process (clk,ready)` and `shiftregister : process (baud_clk, state)` already indicate that you have a problem.

When describing a register, always make sure that your `if(rising_edge(clk))` surrounds ALL of the described logic. A simple registered process should look like this:

```
process(clk) begin
    -- NO LOGIC HERE
    if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        if(reset='1') then
            -- Synchronous reset logic here.
        else
            -- All other logic here.
        end if;
    end if;
    -- NO LOGIC HERE
end process;
```

Comment: I changed my baud_clock and shiftregister processes' sensitivity list to have only single event, but it did not fix latch problem.

Comment: Changing the sensitivity list has no effect on synthesis - it was just an indication for a deeper problem. To fix your latch problem, make sure to change your processes to conform to the template above, especially making sure to have no statements before or after the `if(rising_edge(clk)) then ... end if;` construct.

Comment: If that still doesn't help you, put aside your code and draw a Register-Transfer-Level block diagram of the circuit you are trying to build. This is a very important step when learning HDL - HDL is a hardware *description* language, not a programming language!

Comment: Thanks, but we never learned about drawing diagrams of the circuit, we normally write in programming languages, so all this HDL logic is like black magic to me

Comment: @Ghaad If you are unfamiliar with RTL block diagrams, at the very least you will have to understand what signals are dependent on what other signals. Which signals are combinatorial (based on other signals using only gates) and which signals are sequential (registers). An alternative to a block diagram is a waveform that shows all registers, and how those registers should change at each clock cycle depending on their previous state and the input signals. Note that all registers will change their value simultaneously at a clock edge, while combinatorial signals immediately follow their input.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your 'shiftstate' process, which is responsible for driving 'ready'. How does it drive 'ready' when 'reset' is not 1, and 'start' is not 1? You haven't told it, so it keeps 'ready' unchanged in those cases. That's what 'latch' means: the process needs to remember what 'ready' was before, and keep it the same; your code therefore infers a memory. Make sure that 'ready' is driven in all branches; you can do this easily with a default assignment at the top.

Having said that, your code has multiple other issues. Did someone suggest in another thread that you shouldn't have your rising edge detection inside an if statement? Or was that someone else? Go back and read it again.

Comment: i already fixed problem with rising edge being in if statement. But I don't completly understand what you mean by case when reset is not 1 and start is not 1. By default, ready is set to 0. I am kinda new to vhdl, but in any other language, when if statement is not fullfiled, then the variable wont change, or is it different with singnals? Should I simply put ready <= ready; at begining of 'shiftstate' process?

Comment: You don't have a default on ready - you've specified an initial value outside the process, which is a different thing. Think about execution of the process when for example, reset falls. There is no code path that assigns to ready, so the sim or synth has to remember what ready was before, and keep it unchanged. Think about it - what does 'unchanged' actually mean? It means memory, in hardware design. `ready <= ready` won't make any difference; it still needs memory. Change your logic, or set ready to 0 or 1 at the start of the process.

Comment: Setting ready to 0 or 1 at the start of process wont help, as start/reset are just short signals, so for most time ready would be set to default value. I need it to remember the last one. I though it simply worked as variables in programming languages, where when i'd set ready=1 it would be remembered. Now I understand i was wrong and in VHDL this value is not saved. I still have no idea how to fix this, but thanks for your help.

Comment: It *is* saved! That's what your synthesiser is trying to tell you - it has inferred a latch, which is "memory", which is "saved". It's telling you that because it suspects that there's an error in your logic, and it's probably right. Ignore HDL code - draw a circuit diagram of what you want. If you need something saved, use a clock. If you can't code it, ask.

Comment: but that's what I want, if reset or start is not '1' I want 'ready' to stay the way it was. So if it is saved, then I don't understand why synthesiser sees a problem. Ready should only change if 'start' or 'reset' are set to 1 and then it stays same.

Comment: Can't really help - it's possible that you do need a latch. Look at zennehoy's advice on circuit diagrams - there's no way you can write synthesisable HDL code without at least a basic understanding of digital hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill all the posibilities of if statements so that for every run the program will know which value correspond to a variable. If statement has almost always go with else or elsif options to not produce latches..

Answer (score 0):

A latch can occur when a process is allowed to go from start to finish without the driven outputs being assigned a value.  That is if you have any conditional statements in your process and your outputs are driven inside these conditional statements then there a high chance that the outputs may never be driven. To avoid this it is good practice to place a concurrent statement at the beginning of your process to ensure your outputs are being set at least once.  This will tell your synthesiser not to create a latch.